# Gradle - Shared project dependencies as jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project, that is a service (SOA). 
This project has some classes, like DTOs and Wrappers that I would like to share with the Client-Project (UI).

So I want to build a JAR to share with the project. 
I'ved tried this:

```
// authorization-api.jar
task apiJar(type: Jar) {  
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {  
        include "com/company/sig/authorization/dto**"
    }  
}
```

Two problems: first I want to rename the jar (must be simple, need to search). Second, the JAR was generated empty (with the folders (com/company/sig...) but with no classes :(
Guessing the "sourceSets.main.output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should help You:

```
task apiJar(type: Jar) {  
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {  
        include "com/company/sig/authorization/dto/**"
    }  
    archiveName = 'api.jar'
}
```

As You can see, You're quite close :)